# How to load app conf into Module without subroutine

Tags: perl, mojolicious

Im currently having an Mojolicious app with this structure inside lib folder:

```
 /my_app.conf  - contains secrets, perldoc = 1 and app_mode  = (0 or 1)   
 /lib/MyApp.pm (config is loaded here my $config = $self->plugin('Config');)
 /lib/MyApp/Controller/Home.pm   
 /lib/MyApp/Queries/Main_Queries.pm
```

In /lib/MyApp/Queries/Main_Queries.pm I have queries like

```
our $query1 = "Select * FROM $TBL_ONE";
```

How can i get app_mode from my_app.conf to /lib/MyApp/Queries/Main_Queries.pm **without** using:

```
 sub get_config {
     my $self = shift;
     my $config = $self->app->config->{app_mode}
     return $config;
 }
```

I am trying something like:

```
#/lib/MyApp/Queries/Main_Queries.pm   
package MyApp.. etc
use MOJO::Base
use strict;
use warnings;

use Exporter; 
etc 

my $config = app->config->{app_mode}; #no success
my $TBL_ONE;
# what i want to do next
if ($config == 0) {
    $TBL_ONE = 'blabla';
} else {
    $TBL_ONE = 'blabla_test';
}

our $query1 = "Select * FROM $TBL_ONE";
```

Comment: It would make more sense to use two different databases and simply have different credentials based on which _mode_ you are running in. These modes are often called _environment_, and you would just provide different config files for them. In addition to that, have you considered using DBIx::Class instead of building your own queries from text?

Comment: Using another database is not a solution to his project unfortunately. Basically I am looking for a one liner to read a key value from my_app.conf (without using a sub)

Comment: I'm going to sound like a broken record, but here goes: why?

Comment: The project has access to only one database. Another database can't be requested for this project...

Comment: That's not what I meant. Why do you want a one-liner?

Comment: Your Main_Queries module will have no access to your application or config unless you pass one of those in. Setting them in globals in the module is a bad idea, it means you can never use two versions of it in the same application. You might consider making it an object class instead and instantiating it (creating an object with ->new) with the config it needs. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to get into $config the values of the key from my_app.conf and by using this i can set up development tables and production tables. I am pretty sure I saw somewhere a one liner for this in Mojo, something like app->config->{'key_name'} or something like but I can't find it anymore

Comment: I think it would make more sense to something like a render layer towards the DB that you pass your queries through. Use placeholders in your queries, like `SELECT * FROM {{blabla}} WHERE foo=?`. Then pass that through a helper, like `$c->dbh->prepare($c->sql_renderer($sql_with_table_placeholders))`. With  this `sql_renderer` method, you wrap an object that keeps configuration (or the whole thing is built at startup as a code ref) and knows about your mode, and then replaces the placeholders with the actual names with or without any suffixes.

Comment: So what im trying to do is not possible?

Comment: It certainly isn't the way we'd do it. If two professional developers independently suggest that it is not a good idea that might be cause to reconsider. ;)

Comment: On a different note, I see you're from the UK. If you happen to be from London, there's the [London Perl Mongers tech meetup this Thursday](https://www.meetup.com/London-Perl-Mongers/events/253969340/) in Central London. It's a free evening mini conference with food and drinks. If you're in town, come and say hi!